# How to find file in each directory with the highest number as filename?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file structure that looks like this

```
./501.res/1.bin
./503.res/1.bin
./503.res/2.bin
./504.res/1.bin
```

and I would like to find the file path to the `.bin` file in each directory which have the highest number as filename. So the output I am looking for would be

```
./501.res/1.bin
./503.res/2.bin
./504.res/1.bin
```

The highest number a file can have is 9.

**Question**

How do I do that in BASH?

I have come as far as `find .|grep bin|sort`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using `awk`?  You can get the FIRST occurrence really simply:

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ cat data1
./501.res/1.bin
./503.res/1.bin
./503.res/2.bin
./504.res/1.bin
[ghoti@pc ~]$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="."} a[$2] {next} {a[$2]=1} 1' data1
./501.res/1.bin
./503.res/1.bin
./504.res/1.bin
[ghoti@pc ~]$
```

To get the last occurrence you could pipe through a couple of sorts:

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ sort -r data1 | awk 'BEGIN{FS="."} a[$2] {next} {a[$2]=1} 1' | sort
./501.res/1.bin
./503.res/2.bin
./504.res/1.bin
[ghoti@pc ~]$
```

Given that you're using "find" and "grep", you could probably do this:

```
find . -name \*.bin -type f -print | sort -r | awk 'BEGIN{FS="."} a[$2] {next} {a[$2]=1} 1' | sort
```

**How does this work?**

The `find` command has many useful options, including the ability to select your files by glob, select the type of file, etc.  Its output you already know, and that becomes the input to `sort -r`.

First, we sort our input data in reverse (`sort -r`).  This insures that within any directory, the highest numbered file will show up first.  That result gets fed into awk.  FS is the field separator, which makes `$2` into things like "/501", "/502", etc.  Awk scripts have sections in the form of `condition {action}` which get evaluated for each line of input.  If a condition is missing, the action runs on every line.  If "1" is the condition and there is no action, it prints the line.  So this script is broken out as follows:

- `a[$2] {next}` - If the array `a` with the subscript $2 (i.e. "/501") exists, just jump to the next line.  Otherwise...
- `{a[$2]=1}` - set the array a subscript $2 to 1, so that in future the first condition will evaluate as true, then...
- `1` - print the line.

The output of this awk script will be the data you want, but in reverse order.  The final `sort` puts things back in the order you'd expect.

Now ... that's a lot of pipes, and sort can be a bit resource hungry when you ask it to deal with millions of lines of input at the same time.  This solution will be perfectly sufficient for small numbers of files, but if you're dealing with large quantities of input, let us know, and I can come up with an all-in-one awk solution (that will take longer than 60 seconds to write).

**UPDATE**

Per Dennis' sage advice, the awk script I included above could be improved by changing it from

```
BEGIN{FS="."} a[$2] {next} {a[$2]=1} 1
```

to

```
BEGIN{FS="."} $2 in a {next} {a[$2]} 1
```

While this is functionally identical, the advantage is that you simply define array members rather than assigning values to them, which may save memory or cpu depending on your implementation of awk.  At any rate, it's cleaner.

Comment: It's better to test for existence of an element in an array using `$2 in a {next}`. Doing it that way doesn't create new array elements simply by referring to them. This is what I meant to say the other day when we were discussing this. By the way, if you use `in` that way, you can do `{a[$2]}` instead of `{a[$2]=1}`, but either will work.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson, AH, now I understand what you were getting at the other day.  Thanks very much for the pointer.  :)

Answer (score 3):

Globs are guaranteed to be expanded in lexical order.

```
for dir in ./*/
do
    files=($dir/*)           # create an array
    echo "${files[@]: -1}"   # access its last member
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Tested:

```
find . -type d -name '*.res' | while read dir; do
    find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 | sort -n | tail -n 1
done
```

Comment: Fixed it. find ... -maxdepth 1 shows the path properly now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with someting like this:

```bsh
for dir in $(find . -mindepth 1 -type d | sort); do
   file=$(ls "$dir" | sort | tail -n 1);
   [ -n "$file" ] && (echo "$dir/$file");
done
```

Maybe it can be simpler

Comment: I think you should have sort -n as the numbering probably goes higher than 9.

Comment: @bcelary - the OP stated *"The highest number a file can have is 9."*

Comment: Ah -- sorry. Failed to notice :)

Answer (score 0):

If invoking a shell from within find is an option try this

```
  find * -type d -exec sh -c "echo -n './'; ls -1 {}/*.bin | sort -n -r | head -n 1" \;
```

Answer (score 0):

And here is one liner

```
find . -mindepth 1 -type d | sort | sed -e "s/.*/ls & | sort | tail -n 1 | xargs -I{} echo &\/{}/" | bash
```